# APEX not allowing queries of 3 levels or more relationships

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am having a dilemma of what kind of query shall I make

Imagine that I'm inside a Details View of an object named **Merchandise** and of course, with the scope of LWC coding here, the **recordID** is focused on the Merchandise's.

[image: Production]

I want to create a Lightning Tree where I can display the **Production Requests** related to the **Merchandise** and put the related **Purchase Requests** of these **Production Requests** as sub-trees.

But it seems Salesforce / APEX isn't allowing sub-queries of up to 3rd level.

Legend:
PR = Production Request
PuR = Purchase Request

Relationships
Merchandise has many Production Requests
Production Request has many Purchase Requests

Mechandise > Production Requests > Purchase Requests
(this is the database structure)

I tried querying this

```
List<Merchandise__c> merchanList = [SELECT ID (SELECT ID, (SELECT ID FROM Purchase_Requests__r) FROM Production_Requests__r) FROM Merchandise__c)]
```

And APEX is telling me that I can't query for more than 2 levels of relationship.

Can someone kindly give me a good query or work around for my desired SOQL please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you now know, SOQL only allows us to query one level down a hierarchy. We can query up to 5 levels upwards (e.g. `SELECT Id, Opportunity.Account.Owner.Manager.Profile.Name FROM OpportunityLineItem`) and only one level down.

So you either need to:

- do this in 2 queries (gather the Production Request Ids from the first query, and use those to feed your second query)
- change the object that your outer query is based on so that you only need to traverse down a single level

Both approaches should work, but if you don't need any additional information from `Merchandise__c` (other than the Id) then the second option makes more sense. The query for that would look something like

```
SELECT Id, Parent__c, (SELECT Id FROM Grandchildren__r) FROM Child__c WHERE Parent__c = :parentId
```

Note that it's better practice to simply use the relationship field to get a parent Id (e.g. `Parent__c`) rather than traversing up the relationship to get the Id from the Parent (e.g. `Parent__r.Id`).